# Convex hull of the union of two nonempty sets

Tags: convex-analysis

I was reading about convex hulls on Wikipedia ([Convex hull](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_hull)) and I read :

$ Conv(A \cup B)= Conv(Conv(A) \cup Conv (B))$ where $A$ and $B$ are nonempty sets.

I can see intuitively that this equality is true, but I do not know how to write it formally down.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For simplicity, let us denote $T$ as the operation of taking the convex hull of a set.

We observe following basic principles.

1. $A \subset T(A)$.
2. If $A \supset  B$, then $T(A) \supset T(B)$.
3. $T(T(A))=T(A)$.

Now we prove the proposition.

From 2, $T(A \cup B) \supset T(A)$ and also $T(A \cup B ) \supset T(B)$, so $T(A \cup B) \supset T(A) \cup T(B)$. Hence $T(A \cup B) \supset T(T(A) \cup T(B))$.

On the other hand, we have $ A \cup B \subset T(A) \cup T(B)$. Therefore, $T(A \cup B) \subset T(T(A) \cup T(B))$.